# How to detect if the device is an Amazon kindle in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I want to do something if the device that is running my libgdx app is an Amazon kindle. How do I detect this. I found how to do not using libgdx using android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER, but it doesn't work in a libgdx game. So how do I detect if the device is an Amazon kindle in libgdx?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libGdx platform specific code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743610/libgdx-platform-specific-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two constructors and attributes to your core project class:

```
public String model;
public String manufacturer;

public MyGame(){ }                                //for web, ios and desktop
public MyGame(String manufacturer, String model){ //for android
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.model = model;
}
```

In the *AndroidLauncher* of your android project you can pass the values [Build.MANUFACTURER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER) and [Build.MODEL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL) to your class constructor:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new MyGame(Build.MANUFACTURER,Build.MODEL), config);
}
```

You can have a look in the [device specifications](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/solutions/devices/kindle-fire/specifications/01-device-and-feature-specifications) of amazon with value belongs to the kindle.